# Как подписаться на составной тип данных?

Tags: angular2, typescript, rxjs

У меня есть 3 типа данных:

```
export class Bill {
    constructor(
        public value: number,
        public currency: string
    ) {}
}

export class Category {
    constructor(
        public name: string,
        public capacity: number,
        public id?: number
    ) {}
}

export class WFMEvent {
    constructor(
        public type: string,
        public amount: number,
        public category: number,
        public date: string,
        public description: string,
        public id?: number,
    ) {}
}
```

В компоненте я пытаюсь одновременно получить их при помощи rx-оператора combineLatest так:

```
    private bill: Bill;
    private categories: Category[] = [];
    private events: WFMEvent[] = [];

    Observable.combineLatest(
        this.billService.getBill(),
        this.categoriesService.getCategories(),
        this.eventService.getEvents()
    ).subscribe((data: [Bill, Category[], WFMEvent[]]) => {
        this.bill = data[0];
        this.categories = data[1];
        this.events = data[2];

        this.isLoaded = true;
    });
  }
```

В результате консоль линукса выводит такую ошибку:

> ERROR in
>   src/app/system/planning-page/planning-page.component.ts(35,16): error
>   TS2345: Argument of type '(data: [Bill, Category[], WFMEvent[]]) =>
>   void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: [Bill, Category,
>   WFMEvent[]]) => void'.   Types of parameters 'data' and 'value' are
>   incompatible.
>       Type '[Bill, Category, WFMEvent[]]' is not assignable to type '[Bill, Category[], WFMEvent[]]'.
>         Type 'Category' is not assignable to type 'Category[]'.
>           Property 'includes' is missing in type 'Category'.

При это, если я меняю тип получаемых данных на такой:

```
).subscribe((data: [Bill, any, WFMEvent[]]) => {
```

, то консоль ошибки не выводит и приложение вообще работает без проблем.

Помогите пожалуйста понять почему я не могу указать вместо any конкретный тип? Это было бы аккуратнее и правильнее

Comment: Скорее всего функция `getCategories` имеет не правильный возращаемый тип. Скорее всего он не указан, или указан как `:void`